# JS: Unexpected end of script

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

This is giving me: "unexpected end of script" (the last line).

What could be the problem?

```
(document).ready(function(){

    $(".btn btn-primary").click(function() {
        chooseIngredient(1);
        chooseIngredient(2);
        chooseIngredient(3);
        alert("veikia");
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis

Comment: ...and an opening `$`, assuming you meant to call jQuery's `$` function and pass in `document`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // USE $

    $(".btn btn-primary").click(function() {
        chooseIngredient(1);
        chooseIngredient(2);
        chooseIngredient(3);
        alert("veikia");
    });
}); // HERE you must have ) opened by ready(
```

Comment: Since it's jQuery, you'll also want `$(document).ready`. Otherwise you get `Uncaught TypeError: document.ready is not a function`

Comment: Good point. Thanks.